# Identifying first and last obersvations

Tags: r

I would like to identify the number of firms that start and end each month. My data looks like this, with many more rows and columns.

```
   Firm   Return_1990_01  Return_1990_02 Return_1990_03 Return_1990_04 Return_1990_05 
#1 fg23         NaN             NaN             1.54          2.34        .641      
#2 sdf1         1.35            NaN             3.53          NaN         .231     
#3 sdf1         1.12            2.44            1.51          1.64         NaN
```

One challenge is that a firm can have NaNs in between. For example, Row 2 the firm begins 1990_01 and ends 1990_05 despite NaNs in between.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you attempted to use `dplyr`, `data.table`, or are you staying with base R? Have you tried `by`, `split`, `dplyr::group_by`, or `data.table`'s `DT[, ..., by="Firm"]`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your dataframe is called `df` you could try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  gather(month, value, -Firm) %>% 
  filter(!is.nan(value)) %>% 
  arrange(Firm, month) %>% 
  group_by(Firm) %>% 
  summarise(start = first(month), end = last(month))
```

`gather` transforms your dataframe from a wide to a long format. Next, you filter any `NaN` as they do no matter. Then you seach for the first and last non `NaN` values for each firm.

Comment: thank you - This is very helpful - Any thoughts on how to solve the following error message " Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) : 
  data frame column with incompatible number of rows (465), expecting : 59378"

Comment: Can you provide a (minimal) reproducible example for this error? You can use `dput()` to export your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Find first and last occurrence of !NA per Firm
tt <- apply(!is.na(x[-1]), 1, function(x) range(which(x)))

#Sum up the first/last occurrence in the month
res <- sapply(2:ncol(x)-1, function(i) {c(nStart=sum(tt[1,]==i), nEnd=sum(tt[2,]==i) )})
colnames(res) <- colnames(x)[-1] #Add the Month name
res
#       Return_1990_01 Return_1990_02 Return_1990_03 Return_1990_04 Return_1990_05
#nStart              2              0              1              0              0
#nEnd                0              0              0              1              2
```